# How to deal with growing BIND9 log files

Tags: ubuntu, dns, bind9

My DNS server's logs are the text files that growing too fast and one of them is already over 30 MB in size. I didn't set up the max. file sizes. I would prefer just to manually delete the lines inside the files. Let's say, my log contains entries for the last 10 days.The entries that refer to 9 days I would manually delete and leave there just the last day's entries. Is it something that's not gonna cause any damage to anything, I hope???

Comment: You should explore `logrotate` option, those are set to deal with growing files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Right now I just want to ask about what I was asking in my original post.

Comment: @Gregory And that's exactly what Archemar answered to. `logrotate` is a tool which was created for that very purpose. If you need help in using it, or in writing a small custom rotation script, then at least provide us with a sample of your logs. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will definitely look into logrotate.